# Enhancing antennas to fly from within a building

Tags: antenna

I have an Ardupilot drone with a 5.8GHz video transmitter - xf5804 which sends video to goggles. Furthermore I have Jumper T18 radio transmitter and Jumper R900 receiver. I would like to be able to control the drone and get the video while being inside a building. Are there some antenna enhancers (or whatever) that I can mount on the roof and connect to my goggles/radio transmitter to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really need to do is move the video receiver and antenna outside, and bring the video in on a cable. That used to be easy when the receiver wasn't built into the goggles but it's harder now.

If your goggles have a video-in socket, you can buy a separate receiver fairly cheaply.

Similarly if you have a RC transmitter with a radio module, the module could be mounted outside.

You can't really just move the antennas, as the signal can't be sent over long cables.